# Serialize OpenCv Mat using JSON in C++

Tags: c++, json, opencv

I'm trying to write a TCP client/server application that transmits objects containing OpenCv Mat. I'd like to serialize these objects using JSON. I found some libraries that help me in doing that ([rapidjson](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson)), but they of course do not take into account images as object members.

What would you suggest to serialize in a JSON object a cv::Mat variable? How can I use RapidJson, for example, to achieve that?

Comment: ah, please, **never** try to serialize images into strings

Comment: What would you suggest then? To avoid JSON completely and use standard serialization with boost for example?

Comment: in any case, avoid json serialization for binary things.

Comment: Why not to base64 encode it an bung it into a json object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imencode` can be used to encode an viewable image (with `CV_8UC1` or `CV_8UC3` pixel formats) into a `std::vector<uchar>`. [Link to documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode).

The `vector<uchar>` will contain the same bytes *as if* OpenCV had saved the image into one of the supported image file formats (such as JPEG or PNG) and then have the file bytes loaded back into a byte array.

`imencode` can be found in highgui module when using OpenCV 2.x, or imgcodecs module when using OpenCV 3.x.

With the compressed data in a `vector<uchar>`, you can use Base64 encoding to format it into a string, which can then be added as a JSON value inside a JSON object.

When using JSON to transmit large amounts of data, consider *very very* carefully the character encoding format that the JSON library is instructed to emit. Normally, If a large portion of the data is going to be Base64, you will want to make sure the JSON is emitted in UTF8.

If you have the option of sending in binary (which requires an "out-of-band" design in the web service, something not always doable), it should be seriously considered.

When considering different serialization choices for images, these things should be taken into account:

- Typical image sizes (total number of pixels)

  - Size efficiency is less of a concern if images are small.
- Pixel format (number of channels and precision)

  - Most common image file formats will only allow 8-bit grayscale and 24-bit RGB pixel data. Trying to save higher-precision pixel data into these image formats will result in partial loss of precision.
- Available transmission bandwidth (if it is scarce enough to be a concern). With less available bandwidth, compression becomes more important.
- Compression options.

  - Typical (photographic or synthetic) images are highly compressible due to the common sense that images that are too "dense" will be too hard to comprehend when viewed by human eyes.
  - Compression can be lossless or lossy.
  - Choice of compression may depend on the statistical characteristics of the pixel values (image content).
  - As mentioned above, if compression is performed by encoding into some image formats, you have to make sure the image format can satisfy the pixel value precision requirements of your application.
  - If no existing image format meets your requirements and you still want to perform lossless compression, consider using the `zlib` API that is integrated into the OpenCV Core module.
  - If you are good at image processing and data compression theory, you may be able to devise an application-specific compression method based on your own needs.
  - Remember that reducing the image resolution can be a powerful (*and super-lossy*) way of reducing the transmission file size. Consider carefully what minimum image resolution is actually needed for your application.
- Other considerations

  - Binary or text
  - Endianness
  - Availability of `highgui`, `imgcodecs` or an image decoder for the chosen image format on the receiving end.

*Information source: just did this a few months ago.*